# Parsing Json into array

Tags: iphone, arrays, json

I have the following JSon File,

```
    [
  {
    "Var1": {

    },
    "Var2": "exemple 1",
    "Var3": data,
    "Var4": data,
    "Var5": data,
    "Var6": [
      {
        "Var7": {

        },
        "Var8": 25,
        "Var9": 0,
        "Var10": 0
      },
      {
        "Var7": {

        },
        "Var8": 12,
        "Var9": 1,
        "Var10": 0
      },
      {
        "Var7": {

        },
        "Var8": 12,
        "Var9": 2,
        "Var10": 0
      }
    ],
    "Var11": 300,
    "Var12": data,
    "Var13": 1,
    "Var14": data,
    "Var15": data,
    "Var16": 2,
    "Var17": data,
    "Var18": data
  },
]
```

I want to store the elements into an array so i could access them all. Should i now store every Variable in an array itself, and so have 16 arrays? and then access them? or is there any better way where i could store everything in one array?
I am using the following code to get one variable and get all its entities into one array :

```
NSString *strURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"MyUrl"];
NSData *dataURL = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:strURL]];

NSString *strResult = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:dataURL encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];


NSDictionary *json = [strResult JSONValue];
arrayToUse = [json valueForKeyPath:@"Var2"];
```

Using this code, i will have all the Var2 stored in one array : 
arrayToUSe will have : [@"exemple 1", @"exemple 2 "];
Is there any better way than to store each entity with all its variable in an array ? 
I desire to have : arrayToUse = [Var1,Var2,Var3,…];

Comment: You should be using `NSJSONSerialization` for converting NSData into a JSON object. Not sure what `JSONValue` is?

Comment: This is not a valid JSON

Comment: Just loop through json, pluck out each value, then add it to an NSMutableArray (addObject:).